# I am trying to use redux but it returns blank page when I set up the redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state-management

I have been trying to train my redux skills on a variety of small web projects. currently, I am stuck with this simple web app that gives the color of the blue box
it should in principle return the color red as text. but now I get a blank page.

I have given the code below so its more clear
First I made a new folder and called it redux.

the redux folder has colorSlice.js and store.js

colorSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const colorSlice = createSlice({

    color:'my_color',

    initialState:{
        color:'red'
    },
    reducer:{
        changeColor: (state,action) => {
            state.color = action.payload.color;
        }

    }
   


})

export const {changeColor} = colorSlice.actions;
export default colorSlice.reducer;
```

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import colorSlice, { changeColor } from "./colorSlice";
import colorReducer from './colorSlice'
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        my_color : colorReducer,

    }
    



})
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <App />

   </Provider>
    
 
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function App() {
  const colorbox = useSelector(state => state.my_color.color)
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <div className="bluebox">this is a {colorbox} box</div>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.bluebox{
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 222);

}
```

Comment: Did you get any errors during build? in case you have some strict linting checks even your missing semicolon in store.js line 3 can be a problem.

Comment: even adding that does not change the fact that the app doesnt work. i am really confused as it does not show an error warning or anything

Comment: no error in the browser console?

Comment: oh i found this error on dev tool :
Uncaught Error: `name` is a required option for createSlice
    at createSlice (createSlice.ts:282:1)
    at ./src/redux/colorSlice.js

Answer (score 0):

**Hello bro! You have a syntactical errors, Can you try this please**

**colorSlice.js:**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  color: "red",
};

const colorSlice = createSlice({
  name: "my_color",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    changeColor(state, action) {
      state.color = action.payload.color;
    },
  },
});

export const uiActions = colorSlice.actions;
export default colorSlice;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import colorSlice from './colorSlice';


const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        my_color: colorSlice.reducer    
    }
});

export default store;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './redux/store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>);
```

**App.js**

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const colorbox = useSelector(state => state.my_color.color)
  return (
   <div className="App">
     <div className="bluebox">this is a {colorbox} box</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
.bluebox{
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 222);

}
```